# How to give file path to "save as" window using vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm working on a VB6 code.
It has to perform the following operations in sequence:
1. Check the window is open or not (Done! using FindWindows)
2. Press Ctrl + S (Done! using SendKeys("^S")
3. Type full path name (Stuck here! Don't know how to proceed)
4. Hit Enter key (Done! using SendKeys)

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, _
ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long

'--------------------------------------------------------
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal lhWndP As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal lhWndP As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hWnd As Long) _
As Long
Private Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
Private Const WM_CLOSE = &H10
Private Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
'------------------------------------------------------------

 Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim lhWndP As Long
    Dim lhWndP1 As Long
    Dim hWnd1 As Long
    Dim hWnd11 As Long

   If Dir$("C:\users\public\123.txt") <> "" Then
   Kill ("C:\users\public\123.txt")
   End If

    If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP, "Untitled - Notepad") = True Then
       SetForegroundWindow lhWndP
       DoEvents
        Call VBA.SendKeys("^s")
        DoEvents
       Call VBA.SendKeys("C:\users\public\123.txt") 'This is not working 100%

        If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP1, "Save As") = True Then
        DoEvents
            hWnd11 = FindWindowEx(lhWndP1, 0, "Button", "&Save")
            If hWnd11 <> 0 Then
                Call PostMessage(hWnd11, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
            Else
                MsgBox "Button handle not found!"
            End If
        End If
        hWnd11 = FindWindowEx(lhWndP1, 0, "Button", "&Save")
        If hWnd11 <> 0 Then
            Call PostMessage(hWnd1, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
        Else
           MsgBox "Button handle not found!"
        End If
    End If
    End
End Sub

Public Function GetHandleFromPartialCaption(ByRef lWnd As Long, ByVal sCaption As String) As Boolean
    Dim lhWndP As Long
    Dim sStr As String
    GetHandleFromPartialCaption = False
    lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'PARENT WINDOW
    Do While lhWndP <> 0
        sStr = String$(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
        GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
        sStr = Left$(sStr, Len(sStr) - 1)
        If InStr(1, sStr, sCaption) > 0 Then
            GetHandleFromPartialCaption = True
            lWnd = lhWndP
            Exit Do
        End If
        lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Loop
End Function
```

I tried sendmessage function. But WM_SETTEXT is setting some junk to the window title and not in file name field.

Any alternate for this WM_SETTEXT ? or some other method to accompolish the task?

Note: In this example i've used a notepad. But actual application uses a third party window. I dont have code for that application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't waiting for the SendKeys text to be processed by the target application. A call to [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231254%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) is not the same thing as waiting for an external application to do something.  It allows ***your application*** to flush the rest of ***its*** event queue.

If you need to wait for an external application to process, the quick and dirty way to do it is add a short Sleep.  Declare the API function as...

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

...and then try this:

```
'...
If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP, "Untitled - Notepad") = True Then
    SetForegroundWindow lhWndP
    Sleep 100
    Call VBA.SendKeys("^s")
    Sleep 100
    Call VBA.SendKeys("C:\users\public\123.txt") 'This is not working 100%

    If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP1, "Save As") = True Then
        Sleep 100
        hWnd11 = FindWindowEx(lhWndP1, 0, "Button", "&Save")
        If hWnd11 <> 0 Then
            Call PostMessage(hWnd11, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
        Else
            MsgBox "Button handle not found!"
        End If
    End If
    hWnd11 = FindWindowEx(lhWndP1, 0, "Button", "&Save")
    If hWnd11 <> 0 Then
        Call PostMessage(hWnd1, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox "Button handle not found!"
    End If
End If
'...
```

If that still doesn't work, adjust the Sleep times until it does.

Comment: Thank you comintern :) It worked. As you said, the wait time is not enough for sendkeys. After inserting sleep, it worked fine. For my  application 100ms is enough.